# encoding/csv: Should I use Error() with WriteAll()?

Tags: csv, go

In the golang docs for [encoding/csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.WriteAll), `WriteAll` is stated to `Write` the given CSV records, and then to call `Flush` on the underlying writer.

Now, I'm confused as to whether I should detect errors during `WriteAll` via its return value, or the `Error()` method. Let me explain why.

- `Write` returns `error`. This makes me think I can detect errors based on its return value.
- `Flush` doesn't return `error`, and the docs explicitly say "To check if an error occurred during the Flush, call Error."
- `WriteAll` mentions nothing about error handling, but it returns `error`, and states it performs both `Write` and `Flush`. The docs include an example that goes like this:

  ```
  w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
  w.WriteAll(records) // calls Flush internally

  if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
      log.Fatalln("error writing csv:", err)
  }
  ```
- `Error()` itself states: "Error reports any error that has occurred during a previous **Write or Flush**." (emphasis mine).

I looked at the code and I saw some shenanigans I wasn't familiar with, so I'm turning the question to SO.

Which is it, then? Should I look at the returned `error`? Should I use `w.Error()`? Should I use both? What's the difference?

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by Write/WriteAll. The examples in encoding/csv are explanatory.

Comment: It's in the official docs!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you can use both, i would propose to use the error from

```
err := w.WriteAll(records)
```

this is more common in go.

All errors returned are coming from the *bufio.Writer, and if it fails it will always return an error. So if w.WriteAll returns an error a call to Error() will also return an error.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is a very common pattern in go, that's why I was curious to see the example use a different approach. I wonder if I'm missing some errors with the returned error, that the method catches. Like perhaps if `Flush` throws.